# The way AWS Lambda@Edge accesses to S3 restricted by Object Access Identity (OAI)

Tags: https, amazon-s3, node.js, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lambda

I have a question.
Is the Lambda function (written in node.js) associated with CloudFront accessible to S3 objects restricted by Object Access Identity (OAI)?
If yes, could you tell me how to access?
(access = https.get() or s3.getObject())

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Within the context of the Lambda function that is trying to *directly* access objects from S3, the Origin Access Identity is not relevant... but please try to clarify the question to describe, in precise detail, the entire workflow you envision for the trigger, as well as what problem you are actually trying to solve by attempting this.  (There may be a simpler solution to the *actual problem*, which has not yet been explained.)

Comment: Also note that Origin Access Identities neither *restrict* (deny) nor allow access, they only *authenticate* requests for access.  The bucket policy restricts or allows access, which may be conditional based on the presentation of valid OAI credentials in the request.